# Check for false

Tags: javascript, ajax, if-statement

Is there any better way of doing this?

```
if(borrar() !== false)
{
    alert('tatatata bum bum bum prapra');
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you want to check for false and alert if not, then no there isn't.

If you use `if(val)`, then anything that evaluates to 'truthy', like a non-empty string, will also pass. So it depends on how stringent your criterion is. Using `===` and `!==` is generally considered good practice, to avoid accidentally matching truthy or falsy conditions via JavaScript's implicit boolean tests.

Comment: Yes, for instance, if you compare `0 == false` the result will be `true`, but  with `0 === false` you will get `false`

Answer (score 9):

If you want an explicit check against false (and not undefined, null and others which I assume as you are using !== instead of !=) then yes, you have to use that.

Also, this is the same in a slightly smaller footprint:

```
if(borrar() !== !1)
```

Comment: Agreed, except for `!1`. I wouldn't use that, since it's less verbose than `false`, and also uncommon, hence, less readable.

Comment: true, it's not really a better way, I guess it can be considered a more optimal way for footprint but normally compressor would take care of that so it's not worth using against false.

Answer (score 9):

If you want it to check explicit for it to not be false (boolean value) you have to use

```
if(borrar() !== false)
```

But in JavaScript we usually use falsy and truthy and you could use

```
if(!borrar())
```

but then values 0, '', null, undefined, null and NaN would not generate the alert.

The following values are always falsy:

```
false,
,0 (zero)
,'' or "" (empty string)
,null
,undefined
,NaN
```

Everything else is truthy. That includes:

```
'0' (a string containing a single zero)
,'false' (a string containing the text “false”)
,[] (an empty array)
,{} (an empty object)
,function(){} (an “empty” function)
```

Source: https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

As an extra perk to convert any value to true or false (boolean type), use double exclamation mark:

```
!![] === true
!!'false' === true
!!false === false
!!undefined === false
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use something simpler:

```
if(!var){
    console.log('var is false'); 
}
```

Comment: if var is null or undefined !var is true and is not the point.

Comment: In addition to what @gsubiran noted var might actually equal `false` in which case `!var` would evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 5):

Checking if something isn't false... So it's true, just if you're doing something that is quantum physics.

```
if(!(borrar() === false))
```

or

```
if(borrar() === true)
```

Comment: What if borrar() can return `undefined` or `null`?

Comment: He could ```let borrarReturn = borrar(); if(borrarReturn !== undefined && borrarReturn === true)```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
if(borrar())
{
   // Do something
}
```

If `borrar()` returns true then do something (if it is not false).

Comment: This is a less stringent test than the original, and thus the behaviour will not be exactly the same.

Comment: I guess the question was a better way and i took it as a simpler way, but you are correct this is less stringent. It depends on the borrar() function. Thanks, i'm sure i learn more from answering questions and being corrected than asking my own. :)